# How to grab everything but the first line from .txt with JavaScript FileReader?

Tags: javascript, filereader

I have text file and I would like to grab everything but my first line. Also I would like to check how many columns have each of my rows. How that can be done with JavaScript File Reader? I have used code bleow for reading just the first row:

```
var fileExist = $('#fileUpload')[0];
var reader = new FileReader();
var file = fileExist.files[0];
reader.onload = function(e) {
    var text = reader.result;                 
    var firstLine = text.split('\n').shift(); 
    var columnNames = firstLine.split('\t');

    console.log(columnNames);
}
reader.readAsText(file, 'UTF-8');
```

Comment: So you can have it read the first line, and you want it to read everything **but** the first line.  Can you show code that demonstrates what you have tried in order to read everything **but** the first line since that is your problem?

Comment: I used this console.log(text.split(/\r\n|\n/));  and that grabs entire text file and split in a separate row. I would like to skip the first line.

Answer (score 2):

Just get rid of the first line with `pop()` and then iterate through the Array.

```
var fileExist = $('#fileUpload')[0];
var reader = new FileReader();
var file = fileExist.files[0];
reader.onload = function (e) {
    var text = reader.result;
    var allLines = text.split('\n');

    // Print the colomn names
    console.log(allLines.pop().split('\t'));

    // Get rid of first line
    allLines.pop();

    // Print all the other lines
    allLines.forEach(function (line) {
        console.log(line.split('\t'));
    });
}
reader.readAsText(file, 'UTF-8');
```

Comment: Change pop() to shift() if you want to get rid of the first item in an array (first row in your case)